# I cannot import libraries into python despite repeatedly installing them

Tags: python, pip, python-import, spyder, pydev

I am struggling to install and import python libraries into my programs. originally I was using pydev but I kept getting messages like:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\satur\eclipse-workspace\DMD experimental\Main.py", line 11, in <module> from matplotlib import pyplot as plot ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`

I installed matplotlib using `py -m pip install matplotlib` which produced a few messages like this.

`WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location. WARNING: The scripts fonttools.exe, pyftmerge.exe, pyftsubset.exe and ttx.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\satur\AppData \Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.`

I was unsure what this meant so I tried running my program again and got the module not found error again.

being unable to resolve the issue I moved over to spyder because it came with many of the libraries I wanted thus avoiding the issue. however, as soon as I tried to import and install libraries not included with spyder I encountered the module not found error and a similar warning about the path. I added the paths mentioned in the warning to the PATH in spyder now when I run my code get this error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/satur/.spyder-py3/proper orthogonal decomposition/dynamic mode decomposition experimental driver.py', wdir='C:/Users/satur/.spyder-py3/proper orthogonal decomposition')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\satur\.spyder-py3\proper orthogonal decomposition\dynamic mode decomposition experimental driver.py", line 13, in <module>
    import mat73

  File "C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\mat73\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import h5py

  File "C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _errors

ImportError: cannot import name '_errors' from partially initialized module 'h5py' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py)
```

I did some looking around and found this

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#installing-packages-into-the-same-environment-as-spyder

I followed what instructions I understood

```
import sys; sys.executable
```

`Out[50]: 'C:\\Users\\satur\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Spyder\\Python\\python.exe'`

which is different from what I get when I run it in command prompt or in the pydev terminal both of which give me

`C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe`

when i go to `C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\` I see: 3 versions of idel, 3 versions of pip, and 6 versions of python.

I am deeply confused. I want to install and import libraries into my python programs. I want to be able to run my programs in either (or for that matter any) ide. I seem to be hitting the very similar issues in both. every tutorial I have found online describes the steps to take to do this but not what they are or why I am doing them none of them seem to work and the more times I try to install things the more confused I get.

could someone please explain: how to install and import libraries into a python program. what python is doing when I install things and try to import them. and why both IDEs have similar but different errors.

Comment: I also want to add that when I start spyder I see an error message that reads: "An error occurred when starting the kernel C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.EL2C6PLE4ZYW3ECEVIV3OXXGRN2NRFM2.gfortran‑win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\satur\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.QVLO2T66WEPI7JZ63PS3HMOHFEY472BC.gfortran‑win_amd64.dll
warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"" I am unsure if this is relevant

Comment: Seems like you are using the Spyder standalone installer on Windows. Could you close any Spyder instance, uninstall and reinstall? Also, to use packages outside of the bundled ones that come with the installer this could be useful: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Comment: Any more info on this? I am also getting this error. I am running miniconda and use the standalone spyder on windows. Receiving these annoying errors and warnings when starting up. Reinstalling didn't help.